# Regex for UrlRewriteFilter Tockey

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, java-ee-6

I need a regex for this String below:

```
"/pc020025/verificarStep.do?jsessionid=a875ac311ac8827937575dbcf5843&STEPNAME=ST000002"
```

I'm making this but not this is correct in urlrewrite.xml

```
<from>^/pc020025/verificarStep.do\?jsessionid=([a-z0-9]+)\&STEPNAME=ST000002$</from>
```

I'm using UrlRewriteFilter of the Tockey.

Thank's

Comment: So, what is it you are trying to do, and what is the error/problem?  That regex should match the string, but only if you have the entire string listed (nothing at all before the `/pc` -- no URL no `http://`, etc.).  If all you need is the value of the jsessionid, I'd personally use something smaller, more like JUST `\?jsessionid=([a-z0-9]+)` by itself.

Comment: I need for this string /pc020025/verificarStep.do?jsessionid=bc6235bcc1e5a310d22fdfa2dea4&STEPNAME=ST000002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use this string for your regex
^/pc020025/verificarStep.do(\w)jsessionid=([a-z0-9]+)(\w)([a-zA-Z])=ST000002$